# DLL hell with SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dll

Some of our users are getting an issue with the version of sqlite.interop.dll that is being loaded at runtime, and it's a real head scratcher.

Background:
A WPF application built for AnyCPU, deployed with SQlite .NET and sqlite.interop.dll version 1.0.89. We deploy both x86 and x64 dlls and employ the delay loading included with SQLite.
This has been fine until recently, when we started getting a few support issues from users that had - typically - recently purchased new Dell machines. It seems that there is an older version of sqlite.interop.dll (v.1.0.80) that, *somehow*, is getting loaded in preference to the one we ship. The error we get is a missing entry point, 'sqlite3_changes_interop'.

What we have tried:

1. Changing the setup to simply copy the appropriate dll (x86/64) to the same directory as the executable during installtion (i.e. no separate x86/x64 folders). This means we no longer use the delay loading, as the correct dll is available in the executable directory (although we haven't explicitly disabled the delay loading mechanism in sqlite.net). This doesn't fix the problem..
2. Explicitly loading sqlite.interop.dll when the application first loads. Again, this does not seem to fix the issue.

It seems that the ordering of dll loading locations has been changing somewhat in recent years, and I may not have a good handle on it. I always assumed that a dll in the executable directory would get first preference, and that a dll that had been explicitly loaded would prevent the same dll being reloaded during the application lifetime, so for the life of my I cannot understand what is going on here.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be happening here? The problem is further compounded by the fact that I simply cannot reproduce the problem locally - e.g. by putting the wrong version of the dll in my system path etc. Which makes me think that maybe the GAC might be coming into play?

Really stuck on this one, so any help would be great.

Also - as a final resort - I might consider reverting to the same 1.0.80 version, so that we don't get this issue. Does anyone know where we could source older versions of sqlite.net and sqlite.interop.dll?

**Edit - some additional information:**

The clash is caused by a copy of sqlite.interop.dll version 1.0.80 that is installed with Dell Backup and Recovery. This is installed on all new Dell machines, and users that install our software on such a machine all experience this issue. This Dell software also uses System.Data.SQLite.dll.

The correct version of sqlite.interop.dll is located in the same directory as our executable, and everything I understand about dll loading suggests that this should be loaded in preference.

Although we have not yet been able to reproduce the issue locally, it appears that the bad version of interop.dll is *not* on the path. Furthermore, the Dell backup utility runs automatically on start-up. Does anyone know of any possible mechanism by which this might be hooking into dll load requests and serving the wrong file?

The current line of thinking is that we might build our own System.Data.SQLite.dll and change the interop loading code to a specifically named version (e.g. sqlite.interop.1.0.89.dll). Not a nice solution going forwards, but..

Comment: Is it not that -- since the Dell program is already running -- your requests for the DLL are being satisfied by the already-resident one (unless you specifically name a version)?  Do things work if you stop the Dell program (and/or disable it and reboot)?

Comment: I didn't *think* these kinds of side-by-side issues were around any more(W7/8), but it does seem as if something like is happening. I have asked a user to boot in safe mode and report on whether the issue is gone - just as a diagnostic tool.

Comment: As a follow-up - certainly in the simple test case of having another application that has loaded and is currently using the prior version of sqlite.interop.dll, this does not affect which version our real app loads (I have tested this). So something more is going on..

Comment: Perhaps this is too late, but look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555146/entrypointnotfoundexception-in-system-data-sqlite-after-displaying-folderbrowser) quesion. When the *SQLite.Interop.dll* is registered as a shell extension (in the windows explorer), it will be loaded into your `AppDomain`. There is a workaround described in the answer (using app.config).

Comment: Thanks dymanoid - I think you could be on to something here! Can't confirm this yet, but it does seem consistent with some user reports (e.g. that the error doesn't always happen, and the user does indeed need to open a file browser at first to specify a database filename). Any idea how I could go about installing Sqlite as a shell extension so that I can test this?

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was having and could "fix" with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23603704/1730559) to the earlier question. The problem program was also Dell Backup and Restore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Our app has the same problem.  As you mentioned, the problem is that Dell Backup and Recovery installs a shell extension that uses old versions of several popular dlls. They play hell with any app that launches file dialogs and also uses those libraries, because shell extensions load their dlls into your AppDomain.  The only solution we have so far is to tell the users to uninstall Dell Backup and Recovery.

If you [force your app to load the correct library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555146/entrypointnotfoundexception-in-system-data-sqlite-after-displaying-folderbrowser) as dymanoid mentioned, then your app will crash when it displays a file dialog (because the shell extension will crash).  If you don't do that, then your app will crash when it tries to read from its database.

Interestingly, Dell Backup and Recovery is a repeat offender; it also [breaks QT5](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3526/t/19634253) in the same way.  The [recommended solution](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41416) from the QT guys is to compile your QT library under a different name with the -qtnamespace [name] option.  We might be able to rig something like that with system.data.sqlite, but then we'd have to compile our own version.

Microsoft is [aware of the problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/871790/displaying-a-commondialog-which-displays-a-file-explorer-can-load-assemblies-into-the-applications-appdomain), but has declined to fix it.

I wish the Dell guys had implemented their shell extension [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635410/how-to-disable-shell-extension-in-fileopen-dialog).

[Portroit Pro](https://www.portraitprofessional.com/support/?qid=79), [SONAR](https://www.cakewalk.com/Support/Knowledge-Base/2016000049/Dell-Backup-and-Recovery-causes-a-crash-with-SONAR-2016-08-and-higher), and [AutoDesk](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/infraworks-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/InfraWorks-opening-file-dialog-causes-crash.html)'s solution to this problem is also to uninstall Dell Backup and Recovery.

A typical stack trace of the problem looks this in our application:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. 
at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_open_interop(Byte[] utf8Filename, Int32 flags, IntPtr& db) 
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) 
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open() 
at STCommonShellIntegration.DataShellManagement.CreateNewConnection(SQLiteConnection& newConnection) 
at STCommonShellIntegration.DataShellManagement.InitConfiguration(Dictionary`2 targetSettings) 
at DBROverlayIcon.DBRBackupOverlayIcon.initComponent()
```

So in answer to Track's comment, if you want to detect this particular problem and give the users some special notice, you could do something like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UEHandler;
//...
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] //access violation
static void UEHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e){
  var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
  if( ex.ToString().Contains( "DBROverlayIcon" ){
    //show some dialog here telling users to uninstall DBaR
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I am accepting this as the answer for visibility, although I must give an honourable mention to dymanoid who also mentioned this issue in a comment. We have come to the same conclusion as you and now request that users uninstall the Dell app, but in fact we haven't had a support request on this issue for a while now, so "out of sight, out of mind". The only solution I can think of - unless Microsoft does something to fix this nasty - is to recompile SQLite.NET to use a differently named interop dll.

Comment: This is the exact problem which caused our software crashed in field this morning.

 Fortunately our software installed the Unhandled exception filter, which saved a full-dump(yes).

Opening the dump file in windbg, lm  command shows there're two System_Data_SQLite  module, the other name is System_Data_SQLite_73d20000,

lm v m System_Data_SQLite_73d20000

shows it's absolute path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell Backup and Recovery\Components\Shell\System.Data.SQLite.dll

, which finally leads me to google and here.

Comment: Thanks!
How i can determine using the C#  if 'Dell Backup and Recovery ' is installed on the computer?

Comment: @Track I don't think I'd want to go hunting through the registry or Program Files for it, but the stack trace is fairly distinctive.  I've updated my answer accordingly.  Not sure if that was what you're after, but it should at least help people google this problem.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite.Interop.dll is loaded in a tricky way.
By using any reflector you can inspect UnsafeNativeMethods.Initialize() method in **System.Data.SQLite.dll** by yourself.
Some notes to demonstrate, that it is possible to get something interesting by reflection(1.0.89 version):

- If SQLite.Interop.dll is placed in base directory - it will be loaded
- PreLoadSQLite_BaseDirectory and PreLoadSQLite_UseAssemblyDirectory environment variables can affect loading process
- SQLite.Interop.dll can be searched in predifined subfolders(x86, x64, Win32, Itanium, WinCE)
- Trace.WriteLine is called to inform selected path(not always)

[Source code is also available.](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/source.wiki)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer - I appreciate it. Unfortunately I have been through these steps, and in fact also stepped through the source that handles the interop.dll load, and everything I see suggests that our installation *should* work (i.e. we have the correct interop dll in the same directory as the executable, but the wrong version is still loaded..). I have updated the question with a few more details.

Comment: Have you tried examining the Fusion log to see how the runtime is trying to resolve the reference?

Comment: Can Fusion help with explicitly loaded native dlls? I am (almost) certain that the correct .NET assembly is being loaded, as we wouldn't get the unresolved external if the older one was loading - so there is a mismatch between the .NET assembly and the native interop dll, which is loaded at runtime using LoadLibrary().

Comment: @Matt have you tried to set trace listeners to log the loaded assembly path? Anyway, that's a very interesting issue, it would be nice to know what exactly was happening.

Comment: @FireAlkazar - the big difficulty at the moment is that I can't reproduce the issue locally (I tried to install the Dell utility on several machines, but it failed). Therefore I am relying on (slightly disgruntled) users for information. I was hoping to find out today whether simply stopping the Dell backup service would fix the issue, but the user in question went ahead and un-installed it (the Dell app), which did at least fix the problem - but didn't help much with the diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with this exact issue and the solution we found is to use the bundled package from the System.Data.SQlite website rather than the package from nuget:
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

The bundled dll has both the managed and unmanaged assemblies merged so there is no need for dynamically loading the correct Sqlite.Interop.dll so you don't have the issue of conflicting versions in the appdomain.

When using the bundled assembly you need to include your own logic in your application's installer to decide which dll to copy (x86 or x64).

We haven't had any more issues with conflicting versions since using the bundled assembly.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about the "mixed-mode" assemblies? And these contain everything required, in a single DLL, and nothing needs to be installed in the GAC? Sounds like the easy solution if true - thanks!

Comment: Yep that's right. You still need to download separate x86 and x64 assemblies to target different platforms but you don't need to install anything in the GAC